# Application works only on a freshly started Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, server, glassfish, payara

I have a weird problem.  Whenever I freshly start the server (Payara) and execute my application, it works as intended. It even may work another time.  But then it just throws a `ResponseProcessingException`.
When I restart the server, it works another 1-2 times.

**StackTrace**:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: Unexpected error during response processing.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:881)
    [...] // more ...
    at fish.payara.requesttracing.jaxrs.client.decorators.JaxrsInvocationBuilderDecorator.get(JaxrsInvocationBuilderDecorator.java:195)
    at com.classes.MyClass.myFunc(MyClass.java:10)
    [...] // more ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.SetWithSetter.internalSetValue(SetWithSetter.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.SetValueCommand.setValue(SetValueCommand.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.ReflectionPropagation.setValue(ReflectionPropagation.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.PropertyModel.setValue(PropertyModel.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.lambda$getInstance$0(ObjectDeserializer.java:102)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    [...] // more ...
```

Aaccording to that StackTrace, the Exception is caused by the 10th line of the function `myFunc` in the Class `MyClass`.

**com.classes.MyClass.myFunc:**

```
SomeObject myFunc(String str) {
    return ClientBuilder.newClient()
            .target(str)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // this line
            .get(SomeObject.class);
}
```

As it seems to work at first, I assume, my code is correct. So there has to be something wring with the server?

I'm running Payara 5 on Netbeans 8.2. I've also tried GlassFish 5.

#### Update 1:

**SomeObject.class**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbDateFormat;
import static javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbDateFormat.DEFAULT_FORMAT;
import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbTypeDeserializer;

public class SomeObject {

    private int num1;
    @JsonbTypeDeserializer(AnotherClassDeserializer.class)
    private AnotherClass anotherClass;
    @JsonbDateFormat(locale = DEFAULT_FORMAT)
    private LocalDateTime date1;
    @JsonbDateFormat(value = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date2;
    @JsonbDateFormat(value = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date3;
    private Boolean yesNo;
    private int num2;
    private int num3;

    // constructor
    // default constructor

    // getter & setter

}
```

#### Update 2:

`str` is a URL in the form: `http://someUrl.com/rest/id/123`

`@JsonbDateFormat(locale = DEFAULT_FORMAT)` is the same as `@JsonbDateFormat(value = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")`. It seems to parse flawlessly.

Comment: NOTE: I have no experience with payara. However, From your StackTrace, it looks as though request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) is attempting to deserialize some object into json. Also, from the stacktrace it appears that the object is unable to be deserialized.

Comment: Post the SomeObject class.

Comment: @Dylan: But it **is** able to deserialize it at first. It fails only after 1-2 attempts. This is the weird thing.

Comment: @LppEdd: Please see my update

Answer (score 0):

Can you please print or log "str" ? Then look into console or search after the XXXXXX... pattern

The JSON fields should match the class

```
SomeObject myFunc(String str) {
    System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" + str);  // or put a breakpoint   
    return ClientBuilder.newClient()
            .target(str)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // this line
            .get(SomeObject.class);
}
```

This @JsonbDateFormat(locale = DEFAULT_FORMAT) is very interesting. Can you please look if this pattern is matched ?

Comment: Can you please put it in postman and see what does it return ? You can put it in browseer or POSTMAN. Please check if the result matches the JSON

Comment: Yes, the JSON matches the structure of my Java classes. It works the first 1-2 times, but fails afterwards. And works after a restart of the server again. So I assume, the server is the problem.

Comment: @user1170330 Can you please add AnotherClass ?